# Использование при создании и реализации проекта методологии управления agile scrum

Tags: agile, scrum

Кто нибудь использовал при создании и реализации проекта методологию управления agile scrum?

Интересует то, как приживается данная методология на русских программистах? 
Много ли времени уходит на разработку документа по функциональности проекта и разбиение на спринты?
Можно ли действительно рассчитать очень точно индивидуальные человеко часы на разработку?

P.S.: Интересует русская аудитория.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В нашем проекте уже более года используется Agile Scrum. Сначала все было достаточно строго, в соответствии с рекомендациями. Времени на разбиение работы по спринтам уходило совсем не много, и если задачи были очень хорошо знакомы разработчикам и они реально могли оценить сложность, то, да, получалось оценить по часам, а если нет, то нет.

Но в конечном счете разбиение по спринтам и оценка по часам превратились в формальность, сейчас просто создаются номинальные задачи ("исправление дефектов"), на них навешивается достаточно грубая оценка ("неделя"), а реально сколько получится, столько получится.

Answer (score 9):

- **Время точно рассчитать нельзя.**

> Более того, современные `Agile / Scrum / Kanban` эксперты придерживаются идеи, что время и не нужно рассчитывать - [**5 Reasons Why You Should Stop Estimating User Stories.**](http://www.targetprocess.com/blog/2011/04/5-reasons-why-you-should-stop-estimating-user-stories.html)

- Очень рекомендую пост [**Наш процесс разработки: 50 месяцев эволюции.**](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144051/)

> - Общий смысл примерно в том, что при наличии *адекватной команды и должной мотивации* любой `Agile-like` подход все равно будет модифицирован, исходя из особенностей и места его применения.
> - Главное здесь - не зацикливаться на четком следовании всем правилам `Agile` и `Scrum` и на вторичных вещах типа оптимизации `push / pull` на `Kanban` доске. Все-таки вы делаете **продукт,** а не стремитесь к самому *"труъ 100% аджайльно-скрамовому"* процессу разработки.

Answer (score 4):

У украинских программистов применяется в одной компании 1500+ человек. Часы вычисляются так - описывается задача, почле чего каждый говорит сколько понадобится на это дело времени. Голосуется пару раз, каждый раз после обсуждения, пока не победит большинство, или кто-то кого-то не переубедит. Открытие спринта - день, и закрытие спринта тоже день.

Есть еще канбан, но у кого применяется - не знаю